# Django ValueError: 'dtedeclared with a lazy reference to .....' when changed Model Name

Tags: python, django

This is the first models that I created

```
class IPAddresses(models.Model):
    '''
    @brief      Class for ip addresses.
    @attrs      name        Can be company name
    '''

    ip = models.GenericIPAddressField()
    name = models.CharField(max_length=150, null=True, blank=True)
    active = models.BooleanField(default=True)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.ip



class Authentication(models.Model):
    '''
    @brief      Custom Authentication for dashboard
    @attrs      name    can be a name of a person
    '''


    name = models.CharField(max_length=100, null=True, blank=True)
    password = models.CharField(max_length=200, unique=True)
    ip = models.ManyToManyField(IPAddresses, blank=True)
```

However, I changed the model name of **'IPAddresses'** to **'IPAddress'** and run migrate. It was fine however my next migrates are not and kept receiving this Value Error:

```
  Apply all migrations: admin, auth, cache_admin, contenttypes, core, provider, saba_dashboard, sessions
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "manage.py", line 22, in <module>
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
  File "/Users/deanchristianarmada/Desktop/projects/asian_gaming/radar/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 367, in execute_from_command_line
    utility.execute()
  File "/Users/deanchristianarmada/Desktop/projects/asian_gaming/radar/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 359, in execute
    self.fetch_command(subcommand).run_from_argv(self.argv)
  File "/Users/deanchristianarmada/Desktop/projects/asian_gaming/radar/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 294, in run_from_argv
    self.execute(*args, **cmd_options)
  File "/Users/deanchristianarmada/Desktop/projects/asian_gaming/radar/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 345, in execute
    output = self.handle(*args, **options)
  File "/Users/deanchristianarmada/Desktop/projects/asian_gaming/radar/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/commands/migrate.py", line 164, in handle
    pre_migrate_apps = pre_migrate_state.apps
  File "/Users/deanchristianarmada/Desktop/projects/asian_gaming/radar/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/utils/functional.py", line 35, in __get__
    res = instance.__dict__[self.name] = self.func(instance)
  File "/Users/deanchristianarmada/Desktop/projects/asian_gaming/radar/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/migrations/state.py", line 176, in apps
    return StateApps(self.real_apps, self.models)
  File "/Users/deanchristianarmada/Desktop/projects/asian_gaming/radar/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/migrations/state.py", line 249, in __init__
    raise ValueError("\n".join(error.msg for error in errors))
ValueError: The field saba_dashboard.Authentication.ip was declared with a lazy reference to 'core.ipaddresses', but app 'core' doesn't provide model 'ipaddresses'.
The field saba_dashboard.Authentication_ip.ipaddresses was declared with a lazy reference to 'core.ipaddresses', but app 'core' doesn't provide model 'ipaddresses'.
```

How do I resolve this?

I'm using:

```
Django 1.10.5
Postgresql
Python 2.7
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

the solution is to access the django_migrations table in your database and delete the migration that led to this error. Then go to the your specific app migrations folder and delete the particular migration

this is the last option if 
`./manage.py migrate specific_app <specific_migration_to_rollback_to>` is not working, its a common issue in django version 1.10

Comment: How can I know what migration led to this error in showmigrations?

Answer (score 6):

Just been truggling with such a deadlock myself, keep getting "ValueError: The field ... was declared with a lazy reference to '...', but app '...' doesn't provide model '...'.".

After diving into pgadmin and removing/recovering some tables i actually found that it could also be resolved by adding a new migration that tells django that the referred model has changed:

```
    migrations.AlterField(
        model_name='...',
        name='...',
        field=models.ForeignKey(null=True, on_delete=django.db.models.deletion.SET_NULL, related_name='...', to='<app>.<new-model>'), <===
    ),
```

In addition i had to set dependencies across apps right, so for instance the AlterField should be dependent on the migration that created that model obviously. Don't ask me why it did not work out-of-the-box, i just had to go through this....

Paul

Comment: This should be accepted answer, because it exposes the root cause: the missing dependency.

Answer (score 1):

My problem was that PyCharm's refactor got a bit aggressive and changed the model reference in the actual migrations files.   Reverted the changed migrations and was able to proceed.

In case this helps anybody with newer versions of Django that can usually handle model renames without issue.

Answer (score 0):

This problem is resolved by Django 1.11.  (Or at least, it was for me.)